# How can a cfparam'd variable be undefined?

Tags: coldfusion

A lot of sources call a single resource, typically through `<cfthread ..>`, but some use `<cfinclude ..>`.

Ideally, the code looks for the variable `previous_state`. If some variants are passed, then the resource will attempt to use them.

I received this error:

> Variable PREVIOUS_STATE is undefined.

The line record points to the `<cfif ..>` in this chunk of code.

```
<cfparam    name=       "previous_state"
            default=    "" />

<cfif   isSimpleValue( previous_state )
        and len( previous_state ) eq 0>
    <cfset  previous_state= previousState />

</cfif>
```

My question is how can previous_state be undefined?

I can duplicate it in the application, but it's a fairly complex chain of code using threads. Perhaps the reference was eaten by the garbage collector?

I'm having trouble duplicating it in a simple code segment. I've tried setting the variable to the return of a function with `returnType=   "void"`, but `<cfparam ..>` seems to reset it to an empty string.

Here's the full code context. I removed the unrelated vars and such.

```
// Page
oComponent.foo();

// Component.foo()
<cfset  var local=  {
    previous_state= QueryNew( "foo" , "varchar" )

} />

<cfthread   name=   "foo_#createUUID()#"
            previousState=  "#local.previous_state#">
    <!---   Module does unrelated things... --->
    <cfmodule   template=   "some_module.cfm">
        <cfoutput>
        // unrelated things

        <cfparam    name=       "previous_state"
                    default=    "" />

        <!--- Next line is throwing error. --->
        <cfif   isSimpleValue( previous_state )
                and len( previous_state ) eq 0>
            <cfset  previous_state= previousState />

        </cfif>

        </cfoutput>

    </cfmodule>

</cfthread>
```

I'm now thinking `cfparam` is trying to use a scope that no longer exists by the time this code executes.

Comment: Is the code above defined within a CTHREAD tag?

Comment: Yeah. It's looking like a scoping issue within the thread.

Comment: Definitely a scoping issue. I don't mess around with cfthread enough, but I believe previous_state should be in the attributes scope (attribute.previous_state).

Comment: Why is previous_state defined as a param within the CFTHREAD in the first place? Are you expecting previous_state to be passed to the executing page as a URL/FORM param? If so then defined it outside CFTHREAD and pass as an additional ATTRIBUTE.

Comment: I'm expecting previous_state, but not all calls pass it. For example, the last code segment passes previousState instead. The reason I param previous_state is so I can set it's value if previousState is passed instead.

Comment: I've posted a solution below, you think that would solve your issue here? Looks like you need to pass the 2 values you are comparing through as ATTRIBUTES.

Comment: Finished tracking down the issue. Without specifying a scope, ColdFusion defaulted to using the variables scope. However, the variables scope in this case is the Component's variable scope. If threads are backed up on the server, then the object may no longer exist (garbage collection). I'd expect `cfparam` to fail in this case but it doesn't. I'll have to refactor the code to use attributes scope. Thanks for all the answers, y'all led me to the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code is within a CFTHREAD tag I thing you should be passing `previous_state` as a CFTHREAD attribute, such as:

```
<cfparam name="previous_state" default="" />

    <CFTHREAD previous_state = previous_state
    previousState=  "#local.previous_state#">

    <cfif  isSimpleValue( ATTRIBUTES.previous_state  ) ........

    </CFTHREAD>
```

To quote the CF Docs:

"The Attributes scope contains attributes that are passed to the scope, and is available only within the thread and only for the life of the thread."

Answer (score 1):

For previous_state to be undefined it would need to be null. You would need to do something like

```
<cfif isNull(previous_state)>true</cfif>
```

To prove this try the following

```
<cfset previous_state = "" />
<!--- Change to set previous_state --->
<cfset previous_state = javacast( "null", previous_state ) />

<cfparam name="previous_state" default="" />

<cfif isSimpleValue( previous_state ) and len( previous_state ) eq 0 >
    <cfset previous_state = previousState />
</cfif>
```

Comment: I'm getting a successful execution using that sample on CF8.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you scope your variables properly and your example above has a typo in it. I'm not having an issue running this code on both ACF9.0.1 and Railo 3.3.1.000

```
<cfparam    name=       "previous_state"
            default=    "" />

<cfdump var="#previous_state#">
```

Comment: Beginning to think this is a thread scoping issue. Tracing back the full execution path...